# How to send info to a helper function in jsp?

Tags: java, html, jsp

I am creating a game. The user must login to play the game. Once I click login, it should go to the game. In this game a random number is generated, and 100 buttons. The buttons have 1-100 as values, by selecting one of the buttons, the user is guess the random number. Once a button is clicked it should go to a helper class and compare the results to see if the number clicked matched the random number. Then a appropriate message will display based on the results.

I have created the helper class(GGHelper.java):

```
public class GGHelper extends HttpServlet {
static int randomnum=0;
static String message = "";
public static int randomnum() {
    randomnum = (int) (Math.random() * 100);
    System.out.println(randomnum);
    return randomnum;
}

public static int returnnum() {
    return randomnum;
}

public static String clicks(){
    HttpServletRequest request = null;
int num = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("userEntery"));
if ( num== randomnum) {
        message = "You won";
} else if (num > randomnum) {
    message = "Your guess is too high";
} else {
    message = "Your guess is too low";
}
return message;
}
```

Here is my jsp file(only the body), this is the page that should display once I logged in:

```
<body>
<h1>Welcome to Guessing Game</h1>
<form action=<%=message = GGHelper.clicks()%>>
    <%
        for (int x = 1; x < 101; x++) {
    %><input name="num" type = "submit" value="<%=x%>"><%=x%></button>
    <%
        }
    %>
</form>
<h2><%=message%></h2>
</body>
```

this is the error I get once I logged in:
`java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Helper.GGHelper.clicks(GGHelper.java:43)`

How do I fix this error?

Comment: Try adding parameters....

Comment: Try passing request as a parameter to `clicks()` method...

Comment: @brso05 I did that, and I get this error: `java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)`. It seems that once I log in, it calls the Helper class instead of waiting for the user to click the button

Comment: @thinkingman then remove this line `HttpServletRequest request = null;`

Comment: @thinkingman also make sure you are passing `"userEntery"` parameter to your jsp when it is called...otherwise `request.getParameter("userEntery")` will be null.

Comment: Yes, I fixed the parameter name and removed `HttpServletRequest request = null;`. Still getting the same error.  It seems that once I log in, it calls the Helper class instead of waiting for the user to click the button

Comment: I think you want to submit your form to the servlet to do processing.  Look at `doGet()` and `doPost()` methods of a servlet.

Answer (score 1):

If you read your code carefully, you will see the `null` you try to use as not null:

```
HttpServletRequest request = null;
int num = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("userEntery"));
//                         ^^^^^^^
```